# Socket IO how to send message to one particular person

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Is it good approach to implement private chat with people using SocketIO based on
socket.Id

After I went through documentation only straight forward way is to use

```
io.to(`${socket.id}`).emit("event name",{message:msg,from:socketId});
```

I implemented a test case it works but for me the hard part is that is if one person closes the browser the socketId changes so what is the standard way of notifying every one about change 
Is it possible to reconnect with same socketId

So anyone with experience ,kindly please tell me what is the straightforward way of doing this

Comment: do you want to notify all the users that a user has left the chat?

Comment: Do you have doubt related to the answer I gave?

Answer (score 0):

You can join people to room.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.join('room_id');
});
//Use this on the server side.
```

So once a person emits, you can broadcast his message to rest of the people in the room (or other person in case of private chat) using :

```
socket.to('room_id').emit('Some Message');
```

So instead of sending message using socket-id, you can create a unique key using both the users' email-id(Or any other primary key), and join them to their private room.

Comment: Pranish so, why I got confused with private chat with a room .On what basis a room should be created suppose A and B are there .Should room be created wrt A or B who should join whose room all those are very confusing with socketId its simple .You just send message to user with the userID